# Jquery find identifies incorrect element

Tags: jquery, find, custom-data-attribute

I've got a list of items that contain the data-attribute "data-issueid" which I'm using jquery to add and remove classes from in order to manage the appearance of the active item, compared to the rest.

My jquery "click" function works just fine, it manages the div's classes, and then posts to another page to propagate an associated list into a separate div that is elsewhere on the page.

However, on page load, I need to find that correct div and manage the class without a click.

I'm trying to use the following jquery .find statement:

```
$(".DivSquolQuolIssueID").find('[data-issueid="' + $.trim(IssueID) + '"]').addClass( "DivSquolQuolIssueID_Selected" );
```

It is not finding the proper div, but is instead finding a span child of that div, as shown below:

[image]

As you can see, it tacked on the desired class "DivSquolQuolIssueID_Selected" to the underlying SPAN, and not the DIV.

So, this is really confusing to me.  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `find()` is used to find children.  `filter()` can be used to filter the already found results.

Comment: You can use `$(document).find('.DivSquolQuolIssueID[data-issueid="' + $.trim(IssueID) + '"]')` to find the div with the data.

Comment: @Barmar or the `$(selector, context)` version could be used with the selector and `document`.  But since the document is the default context, slightly unnecessary

Comment: Of course. The important point is attaching the attirbute selector to the class, rather than using find within the class.

Comment: @Barmar he may be wanting to do that for performance reasons.  The class only selector could shortcircuit to the `getElementsByClassName` behind the scenes, instead of going into Sizzle

Comment: @Taplar [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Premature optimization is one thing.  Working good practices into your natural coding reflexes is another thing, and is entirely valid.  @Barmar  obviously, imo

Comment: @Taplar I was just not thinking, it should just be `$(selector)`. I knew something looked funny when I wrote it, since we normally only use `$(document)` in things like `$(document).ready` and `$(document).on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
$('.YourClassName[data-property="someValue"]');
```

Or you could also use:

```
$('[data-property="someValue"]');
```

Comment: I would argue for the first, and against the latter.  The reason being the second selector will perform effectively a complete DOM Scan, as an attribute can be on any element.  The first one will scope down the attributes to at least those matching the class first.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I'm still getting the hang of this.  :)